# setting tint color for navigation bars reverts back to iOS 6 blue color

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an iOS 6 application that sets the tint color for all navigation bar buttons to a green color by using the following:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(100.0f/255.0f) green:(190.0f/255.0f) blue:(100.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
```

This is done at the launch of the application. This works fine on phones running iOS 6 but on phones running iOS 7 the tint color is sometimes there and and sometimes not. It especially happens when an AlertView is displayed. This wipes out the tint color of any buttons displaying the correct green tint and reverts the buttons back to the standard iOS 6 blue tint.

To confirm it isn't something I'm doing in my larger project, I have created a basic template Master-detail xcode project to confirm and only added the above line and an alertview popup and this happens there as well.

I am wondering if 1.) anyone else is experiencing this 2.) if so, have you found a work-around and 3.) anyone know if Apple has confirmed this as a bug.

At this time we are not looking to convert this app to the iOS 7 look-and-feel so that is not an option. Thx.

Comment: First, not happening for me in an empty project. Back button is blue, edit button is green. Not changing after showing and dismissing an alert view. If you want the back arrow green, you need to set the `UINavigationBar` appearance tint, not the bar buttons.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Kevin!! The app is using a custom image for the bar so the tint color for the bar wasn't being set just for the bar buttons and in iOS 6 this works fine, however, when running on iOS 7 it had the odd behavior. Setting the tint for the navigation bar instead did the trick and the custom image covers the bar being tinted. So thank you!

Comment: Kevin if you add your comment as an answer I will mark it as the correct answer for you. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

From the official Apple Documentation:

> In iOS 6, tintColor tinted the background of navigation bars, tab
>   bars, toolbars, search bars, and scope bars. To tint a bar background
>   in iOS 7, use the barTintColor property instead.

You should refer to the complete UI transition guide to see what UI elements behave in a different way in iOS 7. If you want to support both you can check the iOS version and put different code for each version:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

Comment: can we get a link to that documentation and/or the transition guide

Comment: Yes, here it is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1